# I need to get the value from the Database

Tags: android, database

I have finally succeeded in adding another column in the database but now have no idea how to get it out!  This is for a reminder app and the info gets passed to an alarm manager class here

```
public class ReminderManager {

private Context mContext; 
private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;

public ReminderManager(Context context) {
    mContext = context; 
    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
}

public void setReminder(Long taskId, Calendar when) {

    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, (long)taskId); 

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 

    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
}
```

}

It pulls info from a database and is sent by intent from my edit activity here (shortened code)

```
private void saveState() {
    String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    String body = mBodyText.getText().toString();

    SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
    String reminderDateTime = dateTimeFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());

    if (mRowId == null) {

        long id = mDbHelper.createReminder(title, body, reminderDateTime, spinInterval);
        if (id > 0) {
            mRowId = id;
        }
    } else {
        mDbHelper.updateReminder(mRowId, title, body, reminderDateTime, spinInterval);
    }

    new ReminderManager(this).setReminder(mRowId, mCalendar);
}
```

The last line of course setting up the alarm.  I added in a spinner to let the user choose how often the alarm will be set for.  I will change it to setRepeating and add the value from the spinner.  I have the value they chose in the database here

[database picture http://www.bthindiet.com/database.jpg](http://www.bthindiet.com/database.jpg)

If id3 was the last item saved and is passed to my ReminderManager class to set the alarm, how can I extract the value on that row for the spinInterval of 5 hours?  I want to take that string and then I will convert it to a time of (60 * 60 * 1000 * 5) for the setRepeating.

I hope you can help!!

Comment: I think it would be easier to declare your spinInterval as an integer and only keep the hours in (2, 4, 5 etc.).

After just add the label "Every " .. " hours" dynamically in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better insert the `spinInterval` column as integer. So instead of `"Every 5 hours"` it will be only 5. It will be easier.

But if you want to use the current format then just get the String "Every 5 Hour" then parse the number from the String. As it seems your `spinerInterval` string format is always same then you can easily parse the number

```
String s = s.subString(6,7);
```

Comment: I agree it would be easier to insert it as an int and then can setRepeating as (60 * 60 * 1000 * s)?  I guess I don't understand the (6,7) part. I need to grab the currently saved item to set the alarm. The last record saved had id #3 in the example.  Sorry for my ignorance!

Comment: @JeffK 6, 7 is to get the substring.. in the 6th postion of you number there is the digit .. so parsing from there